# Can not export material from blender to three ja

Tags: web, 3d, three.js, blender

I try to export object from 3d blender to three.js . And it's work but three.js doesn't show material and texture. I have last versions of Blender and three.js .

Thank you

Comment: Add more information. What do do you see? Do you see the model at all? Does your model have UVW coordinates?

Comment: Yes it has uvs coordinates and I can see model but without material

Comment: Show us your code, specifically how you are loading the model and creating the material.

Comment: Did you use cycles in blender? The cycles node based materials don't export well and will need to be baked to an image texture to use them elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you select "**Geometry**" as type and not *BufferedGeometry*

[image]